# self.tabbar custom height white background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

[image]

```
        UIImage *TabBarFooterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b_bar"];
        CGRect viewFrame = self.tabBar.frame;
        viewFrame.origin.y +=4; //the correct position of the tab bar
        viewFrame.size.height = 45; //the correct height
        self.tabBar.frame = viewFrame;
        [self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:TabBarFooterImage];
```

I have set a custom height to tabbar. There is a white line on tabbar. how do I remove it?

Comment: There is no white line , it is your tab bar frame that needs to be adjusted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you.

```
imgTab = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320.0,50)];
imgTab.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottambar.png"];
tabBarController.tabBar.tag=10;
[tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:imgTab];
```

Comment: set your frame according to your wish.